# Add borders or margins to table rows using CSS

Tags: css, border, margin, css-tables

I need to adjust a table using only CSS (cannot change the HTML apart from adding classnames where needed.)

I want to add a white border to the top of one `tr` to which I have assigned the class `.rowOne`. Alternatively, adding a margin could also work as the background of my page is white, so just a margin between would give the same result as a white `border-top`

For some reason any CSS I apply to the `rowOne` class doesn't work.

[JS Fiddle to show problem](http://jsfiddle.net/YgSYT/)

CSS for `.rowOne`

```
table .rowOne{
    border-top:8px solid #fff;
}
```

Any reason this doesn't work? How can I style this row to have a gap/border/margin?

Answer (score 1):

```
table .rowOne td {
    border-top:8px solid #fff;
}
```

That seems to work, no idea why it doesn't work directly on the tr. Also you're using a bunch of deprecated attributes, you should consult here for some info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/table

Answer (score 0):

The border works, its just that you don't see it because its under the first tr.

What you need to do is to set a float property to the tr.

something like.

```
table.deliveryTbl tr {

    float: left;   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a border collapse to the table it seems to help but there could be side effects that I haven't thought about.

```
table.deliveryTbl
{
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-color:transparent;
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```